# Constructor and object intitiation

Tags: programming-languages

When we access "this \ Me" in the constructor of any class, how is it that "this" is already available while its yet getting constructed? Has a temporary creation of the instance already happened before the constructor call? If so then does this mean these Constructors are called after the actual object initialisation?

Comment: How you view this is likely to be language-specific. Please tell us which languages you're interested in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the object is created and the memory is allocated before you initialize it with the constructor....
ex
1. you create the object;

```
MyObject myObject;
```

2. you initialize it

```
myObject = new MyObject();
```

these 2 steps are also done when you are doing this:

```
MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
```

Edit:
in the constructor `this` goes for `myObject`

Answer (score 0):

In C++, when you have

```
Foo::Foo(int x)
: frob(x) {
    this->frob = x;
}
```

then the construction really happens exactly between then `:` and the first brace:

```
:<here>{
```

In the the body of that constructor, the object *is* fully constructed, therefore, using `this` there is well defined.